# Does SQL Server 2012 work with Visual Studio 2008 applications?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2012-express

Does SQL Server 2012 or SQL Server Express 2012 work with Visual Studio 2008 applications?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506933/does-sql-server-2012-work-with-visual-studio-2008

Comment: **YES!** - why do you ask? What's your issue / problem? As long as your VS 2008 app uses ADO.NET to connect to SQL Server - any version of SQL Server - from 2000 to 2012 - will be supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as your "old" VS 2008 app doesn't use [any of the (few) deprecated features of SQL Server 2012](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143729.aspx) - then yes - I don't see any reason why it shouldn't work.

The key is the use of ADO.NET - it's really more about which database access technology (and which version of the .NET framework) you're using - rather than what Visual Studio version your app was written in. To the app, it's just a server you connect to - using ADO.NET and a connection string - and then you fire off SQL queries against it.

ADO.NET is the preferred way to connect to SQL Server from any .NET application, and it should support **any** version of SQL Server - from 2000 through 2012 and any edition (Express, Web, Standard, Enterprise, DataCenter - you name it).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely vs2012 is compatible with sql server 2008

Here are other compatibility points :-
Visual Studio 2012 is compatible with sql server 2008/ 2008 R2
Visual studio 2010 is compatible with sql server 2008 / 2005
Visual Studio 2008 is compatible with sql server 2005

Comment: Isn't this the opposite of what the OP is asking?